# Is there any way to set stored procedure options like ANSI_NULLS to ON or OFF outside of creation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'd like to set ANSI NULLs and quoted identifier properties on a stored procedure after it has been created.  Is this possible?

For some context, I'm using Visual Studio Database Projects / SSDT, and it appears these values can only be set at the database level, not on the procedure level.  However, we're using an existing database with inconsistently created procedures, so I'd like to preserve the current behavior until we can normalize them.

Comment: When happens when you `SET` and then `ALTER`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand wouldn't I have to basically redeclare the procedure in that case?

Comment: Yes, why is that a problem? Right-click > modify. If you need to do it for many procedures, this is easy to automate.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it doesn't exactly fit the database project paradigm though where you have a single canonical "create procedure" statement and the SSDT tooling creates the alter when there are modifications for deployment

Comment: @AaronBertrand but are you saying it's basically impossible outside of a CREATE / ALTER PROCEDURE statement and setting those properties right before it?

Comment: Are you trying to uphold some classroom database project paradigm, or are you trying to fix a handful of procedures that were created with the wrong settings?

Comment: Right, I don't know of a way to say `UPDATE dbo.procedurename SET ANSI_NULLS = ON;` - the setting is inherited from the session that creates the object (and maybe alters, I haven't confirmed).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I wouldn't call it a classroom paradigm, but yes this is for working with database projects specifically.  The procs need to preserve their settings every time they are modified, but deploying with database projects use the settings specified for the database (which would blow them away).  Knowing it is probably not possible is helpful though.

Comment: It's stored in the metadata about the object, and I think you can set it through SMO though that essentially is rescripting it.

Comment: You can see the value in sys.sql_modules that the object was created with.

Comment: @AaronBertrand et, al: The value of `uses_ansi_nulls` as reported by `sys.sql_modules` _can_ be changed via an `ALTER` statement. I just tested and confirmed it.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tested this on other versions of Visual Studio, but with version 12.0.3 (Update4) there is an option to override the ANSI Nulls config at the database-level specification for a single procedure in an SSDT project.

Just right-click the procedure in solution explorer and choose properties...

[image: override ansi nulls for single procedure]

Comment: It should be made clear in this answer that this functionality is more so dependent on SSDT and the particular version of it that is installed, and not specifically on Visual Studio.

Comment: fair point... SSDT v12.0.50730

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as it is stated in the title, without regards to the additional detail of wanting to do this via a Visual Studio / SSDT project:

Yes, it is possible to change certain options after creation by simply issuing an `ALTER` statement. The options that can change for Stored Procedures, at the very least, are:

- ANSI_NULLS
- QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
- WITH RECOMPILE
- WITH ENCRYPTION
- WITH EXECUTE AS

For `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`, just issue the appropriate `SET` statement and then issue the `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement with the exact same definition that it currently has.

For the `WITH...` options, you need to start with the current definition, and then add the appropriate `WITH` option(s), and then run the `ALTER` on the modified definition (since the `WITH` clause is part of the object definition, whereas `SET` session properties are not).